# Cannot read properties of null (reading '_doc')

Tags: graphql

I'm running a query in GraphQL and getting this error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot read properties of null (reading '_doc')",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 38,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "songs",
        0,
        "creator"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

This is the query.

```
query {
  songs {
    song_file_name
    song_type
    song_size
    user_name
    creator {
      email
    }
```

[This](https://gist.github.com/TheNomadicAspie/38ed98f9a2a83ee901cd8eb3ccb5fcd8) is my resolver file, and this is the schema.

```
const { buildSchema } = require('graphql');

module.exports = buildSchema(`
type Song {
  _id: ID!
  song_file_name: String!
  song_type: String!
  song_size: Int!
  user_name: String!
  creator: User!
}
type User {
  _id: ID!
  email: String!
  password: String
  createdSongs: [Song!]
}
input SongInput {
  song_file_name: String!
  song_type: String!
  song_size: Int!
  user_name: String!
}
input UserInput {
  email: String!
  password: String!
}
type RootQuery {
    songs: [Song!]!
}
type RootMutation {
    createSong(songInput: SongInput): Song
    createUser(userInput: UserInput): User
}
schema {
    query: RootQuery
    mutation: RootMutation
}
`);
```

Could anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? It looks like creator is returning null, but it is properly defined as far as I can tell. What's causing this?

Also, can anyone suggest a good place to learn GraphQL? I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bgq7FRSPDpI&list=PL55RiY5tL51rG1x02Yyj93iypUuHYXcB_&index=9) guide and though I find it useful and informative, it quickly gets to a level where I don't feel I fully understand what I'm doing although I'm following along.

I know the basics of GraphQL, but the relational concepts is hard for me to wrap my head around.

Comment: Please show errors

Comment: The error is at the top of the post?

Comment: One line no stack trace ?

Comment: That's the output of the GraphiQL console, the server I'm running doesn't show anything when that error occurs, and neither does the console in Chrome developer tools. The integrated console for GraphiQL is the only place I see the error, and I posted the entirety of it. Is there somewhere else I should be looking?